# Token Input Ondelete is not working

Tags: jquery-tokeninput

I have a form where i have used token input plugin to select multiple items from a predefined list. However Ondelete function is not working.

```
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            $(document).ready(function() {
                                var1_ids = '<?php echo $records[0]['team_member']?>';
                                $("#team_member").tokenInput("<?php echo base_url(); ?>staff_activity/get_members", {
                                    theme: "facebook",
                                    prePopulate: [<?php echo $show1; ?>],
                                    resultsFormatter: function(item){ return "<li>" + " " + "<div style='display: inline-block; padding-left: 5px;'><div class='full_name'>" + item.first_name +   "</div></div></li>" },
                                    tokenFormatter: function(item) { return "<li><p>" + item.first_name +  "</p></li>" },

                                    onAdd: function (item) {

                                        var1_ids = var1_ids + item.staff_id + ',';
                                        $('#team_member_ids').val(var1_ids);



                                    },
                                    onDelete: function (item) {
                                        var1_ids = var1_ids.replace(item.staff_id+',','');

                                        $('#team_member_ids').val(var1_ids);
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                        </script>
```

where var_dump($records[0]['team_member']?>); is string(11) ",900,4,979,"